# Do the free neutrons in a neutron star sometimes decay and immediately re-form?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons, neutron-stars

Is there any way of confirming this, one way or the other?  Would it affect any of the star's 'observeables', so to speak?

I know that two similar questions are up on Stack Exchange-physics, and I asked a somewhat similar question about whether hydrogen atoms occasionally form short-lived neutrons...

The answers talk about how energetically unfavorable these events would be, but...

Even energetically unfavorable things sometimes happen, correct?

Comment: I doubt you'll get a better answer than https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105475/123208

Answer (score 7):

If the neutrons in a neutron star decayed on a 10 minute timescale, but were in equilibrium with the reverse process of neutronisation, then a neutrino-antineutrino pair would be emitted for each neutron decay.

Since the neutrinos can easily escape from the neutron star, because the neutrons are degenerate, each neutrino would take away $\sim k_BT$ of energy.

But the thermal energy content of a degenerate neutron gas is $\ll k_B T$ per neutron, so a neutron star would lose all its thermal energy on a timescale $\ll 10$ minutes.

We know this doesn't happen, since thermal emission can be detected from neutron stars hundreds of thousands of years after they were born (e.g. [Sartore et al. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2121)).

Instead, although there is a very short period (seconds) where very rapid neutrino cooling is possible, once a degenerate state is approached then further beta decay is almost blocked by degenerate electron and proton gases formed as decay products and the cooling becomes *much* slower. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105475/123208