# Could quark star becomes a neutron star?

Tags: quarks, neutron-stars

Fusion of quarks release 8 times more energy than hydrogen fusion, so I was wondering if quark star exists and before quark degeneracy pressure kicks in wouldn't these tightly packed sea of quarks start fusing and eventually becoming a miniature neutron star?

I think in normal scenario due to the short range of strong force and quark/neutron cannot be found alone in nature compare to the condition of quark star where quarks should easily fused with each other and outshines almost everything in the night sky.

Comment: You got this in reverse. You need to add this much energy to split neutrons into quarks. So the quark star is a hypothetical star that forms in a collapse of a large neutron star. The range of mass for a quark star is rather narrow. Slightly less and it is a neutron star. Slightly more and it collapses to a black hole. Also, the strong force is not short range. You need a force of 50 tons to pull two quarks apart and this force does not decrease with the distance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How big of a neutron star would be needed to form a quark star inside of it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275744/)

Comment: The question I've linked may not seem an obvious duplicate, but the answers to it explain how the (hypothetical) quark stars form so they do answer your question as well.